# Use something like decodeByteArray to existing bitmap

Tags: android, arrays, image, image-processing, bitmap

I have refreshable byte array with bytes that contains my image data.

On each refresh I use `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byte[] data, int offset, int length)` in background thread that creates new bitmap instance on each refresh.

Its spends a lot of time and make some freezes.
Can we create bitmap before we are start all refresh schedulers. And than update exist bitmap from new byte array, without creating new instances on each schedule?

Comment: `BitmapFactory.Options.inBitmap` ? but I'm sure that it will not help with freezes ... as most of time takes decoding itself not memory allocation

Comment: @Selvin thank you for answer. i try, it rise IllegalArgumentException "Problem decoding into existing bitmap"

Comment: Bitmap used for reuse should be mutable ... please do some reasearch

Comment: @Selvin my existing bitmap returns IsMutable = true.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't fit (is bigger) ... but seriously ... it will not your freezes ... try to use smaller bitmap

Comment: @Selvin ok, but how to do it?
thanks for the explanation. i use DefaultHttpClient.Execute(req) for getting stream of camera, and than translate some bytes from stream to the bitmap. In brief (BufferedInputStream)response.getEntity().getContent it is my data.

Comment: Bitmap class for video streaming? ...  ... better find some streaming library ... showing frame by frame using Bitmap class will always be slow

Comment: @Selvin yes, but format of video is MJPEG, android video viewer not supports this format.

Comment: maybe we can create bitmap with specific small resolution from stream, and not decode all stream, i thinks it must be very fast.